# how to mine this facebook post in R?

Tags: r, facebook

I want to get my feet into facebook mining and I have seen an interesting post which I want to extract:

```
https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10103253901916271
```

This post is from Mark Zuckerberg and it is about the election in the US in 2016.

I installed the Rfacebook and RCurl packages and I also read the documentations.

The statement of

```
page <- getPage(page="humansofnewyork", token=fb_oauth, feed=TRUE)
```

just works for pages. Is there something so I can scrape from Zuckerberg's post with the id 10103253901916271?

```
page <- getPost("10103253901916271", mytoken , n = 100)
```

gave me the error

```
Error in callAPI(url = url, token = token, api = api) : 
(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher
```

changing to

```
page <- getPost("10103253901916271", mytoken , n = 100, api ="v2.3")
```

gave me same error as well:

```
Error in callAPI(url = url, token = token, api = api) : 
(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know if this is of help, hence the comment and not answer, but I am able to use `getPost` to get the comments from my company's Facebook page. First, we extract post id's via `getPage`, then iterate over the id's using a `for` loop and `getPost`. The id looks different than what you have, it's in the format of [15 len number]_[15 len number]. Looking now, it looks like the first 15 numbers are the page id as they don't vary from post to post.

Answer (score 1):

Scraping is not allowed on Facebook, and API access to the posts of a user profile is only possible by authorizing that user with the `user_posts` permission. The only way to do this is to ask Mark Zuckerberg to authorize your App with the `user_posts` permission and use his User Access Token.

In other words: it is impossible.

Comment: So these tutorials and books are also illegal?

Comment: what tutorials and books exactly? the terms are here: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php - rule of thumb: if it´s not possible with the api, it´s not allowed. and getting ANY data of a user (no matter if it is public) requires that the user authorizes your app with the appropriate permissions. else, it would not even make sense to have a permission like "user_posts" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment..

You'll need to put the id in the getPost as [pageid]_[postid].

Here is an example from your humansofnewyork page:

```
page <- getPage(page="humansofnewyork", token=fb_oauth, feed=TRUE)

page$id[8]
# [1] "102099916530784_2103238599750229"

post <- getPost(post = page$id[8], n = 100, token=fb_oauth, likes=FALSE)
```